# How to use Group By statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Iam trying to use group by statement but it gives me this error :- Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

But I need to group them accordind to their Feeid.

```
select st.ID,af.Fee_Head_Name,SUM(Amount) as tamt from admission af join 
student st on af.ID= FeeID group by FeeID
```

Without SUM(Amount)(means simply Amount) and Group by statement iam getting output like this:

```
Fee_Head_Name | Amount
Admission     | 5000
Tution        | 2500
Games         | 1500
Tution        | 2500
Games         | 1500
```

But my desired must look Like this :-

```
Fee_Head_Name | Amount
Admission     | 5000
Tution        | 5000
Games         | 3000
```

Please help me on this iam stuck here for so long and used almost everything but nothing work

Comment: `GROUP BY Fee_Head_Name`

Comment: You can only use GROUP BY on columns that are part of the SELECT statement

Comment: Use `GROUP BY FeeID, af.Fee_Head_Name`

Comment: Even if use Fee_Head_Name it gives me same problem

Comment: Show us what exact query you used. it shouldn't give you an error in that case.

Comment: Is this a typo  on `af.ID= FeeID`?Probably you are missing the table alias before FeeID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT Fee_Head_Name , SUM(Amount)

FROM TABLE1

GROUP BY Fee_Head_Name
```

## [GROUP BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

**EDIT**

IF you want to select ID also then use this

```
 SELECT MIN(ID),Fee_Head_Name , SUM(Amount)

 FROM TABLE1

 GROUP BY Fee_Head_Name
```

Comment: But as and when i use another column then again it gives me same error. Like when this SELECT Fee_Head_Name , SUM(Amount)

FROM TABLE1

GROUP BY Fee_Head_Name

Answer (score 1):

```
select af.Fee_Head_Name,SUM(Amount) as tamt from admission af join 
student st on af.ID= FeeID group by af.Fee_Head_Name
```

group by with column in your select statement

Answer (score 0):

```
select af.Fee_Head_Name,SUM(Amount) as tamt from admission af join 
student st on af.ID= FeeID GROUP BY Fee_Head_Name
```

You should use the above query . Group By is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Fee_Head_Name,
       SUM(Amount) 
FROM admission 
GROUP BY Fee_Head_Name
```

See this link for more details http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp